# How can I center my html form?

Tags: html, css

So I watched this tutorial on how to create a good contact me form. But the problem is I am having trouble centering it. It uses some grid tags and it responsive. So I would like to keep the responsive there but when in full width I want it to be centered like the logo is. (New to HTML & CSS just learning)
HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
<div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">

  <div class="contact">
    <h3>Email Us</h3>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
    *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#485e74;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding:1em;
}

.container{
  max-width:1170px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:1em;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

.brand{
  text-align: center;
}

.brand span{
  color:#fff;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7);
}
*/
.wrapper > *{
  padding: 1em;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.company-info{
  background:#DA00F0;
}
*/

/*
.company-info h3, .company-info ul{
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 0 1rem 0;
}
*/
.contact{
  background:#f9feff;
}

/* FORM STYLES */
.contact form{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:20px;
}

.contact form label{
  display:block;
}

.contact form p{
  margin:0;
}

.contact form .full{
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button, .contact form input, .contact form textarea{
  width:100%;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid #c9e6ff;
}

.contact form button{
  background:#c9e6ff;
  border:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact form button:hover,.contact form button:focus{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#fff;
  outline:0;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

/* LARGE SCREENS */
/*Once it passes 700px do this */
@media(min-width:700px){
  .wrapper{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;

  }

  .wrapper > *{
    padding:2em;
  }

   .brand .contact{
    text-align: center;
  }


}
```

Comment: flexbox. Whenever you're going to ask "how do I center/align ..." the answer in 2017 and beyond is automatically flexbox. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://flexboxfroggy.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @media(min-width: 700px){
.wrapper {
    /* remove this 
     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
    *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#485e74;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding:1em;
}

.container{
  max-width:1170px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:1em;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

.brand{
  text-align: center;
}

.brand span{
  color:#fff;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7);
}
*/
.wrapper > *{
  padding: 1em;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.company-info{
  background:#DA00F0;
}
*/

/*
.company-info h3, .company-info ul{
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 0 1rem 0;
}
*/
.contact{
  background:#f9feff;
}

/* FORM STYLES */
.contact form{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:20px;
}

.contact form label{
  display:block;
}

.contact form p{
  margin:0;
}

.contact form .full{
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button, .contact form input, .contact form textarea{
  width:100%;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid #c9e6ff;
}

.contact form button{
  background:#c9e6ff;
  border:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact form button:hover,.contact form button:focus{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#fff;
  outline:0;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

/* LARGE SCREENS */
/*Once it passes 700px do this */
@media(min-width:700px){
  .wrapper{
      display: flex;
     justify-content: center;

  }

  .wrapper > *{
    padding:2em;
  }

   .brand .contact{
    text-align: center;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
<div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">

  <div class="contact">
    <h3>Email Us</h3>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

While you could use `margin: auto`, you *might* stumble upon weird behaviors if you use grid somewhere not shown in your code.

Further reading:

- [Css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
- [A guide to css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at these links you suggested

Answer (score 1):

This code could be of help, basically I have removed the code that is affecting the container of the form and added so that it will work in responsive in a single field.

**CSS:**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#485e74;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding:1em;
}

.container{
  max-width:1170px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:1em;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

.brand{
  text-align: center;
}

.brand span{
  color:#fff;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7);
}
*/
.wrapper > *{
  padding: 1em;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.company-info{
  background:#DA00F0;
}
*/

/*
.company-info h3, .company-info ul{
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 0 1rem 0;
}
*/
.contact{
  background:#f9feff;
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* FORM STYLES */
.contact form{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:20px;
}

.contact form label{
  display:block;
}

.contact form p{
  margin:0;
}

.contact form .full{
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button, .contact form input, .contact form textarea{
  width:100%;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid #c9e6ff;
}

.contact form button{
  background:#c9e6ff;
  border:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact form button:hover,.contact form button:focus{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#fff;
  outline:0;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .contact{
    max-width: inherit;
  }
  .contact form {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**EXAMPLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/8dvch6nj/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you wanted to keep the entire block in grid format, you could always change .wrapper to not use the grid, but just have a margin of 0px auto.  If you wanted to still use grid layout, you could just change .wrapper to a width of 100%

```css
    *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#485e74;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding:1em;
}

.container{
  max-width:1170px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:1em;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}

.brand{
  text-align: center;
}

.brand span{
  color:#fff;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7);
}
*/
.wrapper > *{
  padding: 1em;
}
/* REMOVE */
/*
.company-info{
  background:#DA00F0;
}
*/

/*
.company-info h3, .company-info ul{
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 0 1rem 0;
}
*/
.contact{
  background:#f9feff;
}

/* FORM STYLES */
.contact form{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:20px;
}

.contact form label{
  display:block;
}

.contact form p{
  margin:0;
}

.contact form .full{
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button, .contact form input, .contact form textarea{
  width:100%;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid #c9e6ff;
}

.contact form button{
  background:#c9e6ff;
  border:0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact form button:hover,.contact form button:focus{
  background:#92bde7;
  color:#fff;
  outline:0;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}

/* LARGE SCREENS */
/*Once it passes 700px do this */
@media(min-width:700px){
  .wrapper{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;

  }

  .wrapper > *{
    padding:2em;
  }

   .brand .contact{
    text-align: center;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
<div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">

  <div class="contact">
    <h3>Email Us</h3>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```